# Getting the index of the leftmost slide in Tiny Slider

Tags: javascript, plugins, tiny-slider

**What I have**

I'm using Tiny Slider. I want to create click events on each of my slides to find out if  the leftmost slide was clicked or another one was.

**What I have tried so far**

I thought that `slider1.getInfo().displayIndex` was the way to go until I realized the display index is not the same for a left navigation arrow event (gives you the rightmost slide number) and a right navigation arrow event (gives you the leftmost slide number). And then on top of that clicking on any slide and then printing out `slider1.getInfo().displayIndex` gives me the same index for each of my three slides.

**So my question is:**

How do I find out what is the index of my leftmost slide?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't receive answers, but I was able to find the solution. It's just as simple as one could wish for.

Basically, you just have to find the first class called .tns-slide-active in the DOM. These classes are added automatically to slides that are visible to the user.